# StatsModels not aligned Error

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am getting an error when I try to run a multivariable linear regression in Statsmodels.  Everything works fine when I hardcode just one X column in the XData variable.

Can someone please give me some advice as what I'm missing here?  I would greatly appreciate it.

Error:

ValueError: shapes (747,2) and (747,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 747 (dim 0)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import itertools

data = pd.read_csv("deaconFoodData.csv")

for i in range(2,10,1):
    xCombinations = itertools.combinations(["Food Exp","HH Size","HH Inc","Highest Ed Head","Age Head","Shopping Time","Kid <6","Kid 6-18","Eating Healthy"], i)
    print(str(i) + " variables")
    for combination in xCombinations:

        comb = list(combination)

        print(comb)
        xData = data[["Food Exp", "HH Size"]] # data[comb]
        yData = data["Shopping LH"]
        yData = sm.add_constant(yData, prepend=False)
        print(yData)
        # Fit and summarize OLS model
        mod = sm.OLS(xData, yData)
        res = mod.fit()
        print(res.rsquared)
```

GitHub Link:
https://github.com/deacons2016/DeaconFood

Comment: OLS regression can deal with multiple predictors (what you are calling `yData`), but not multiple outcomes (your `xData`).  Regression with multiple outcomes is usually referred to as "multivariate regression".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.   Ydata only has one column,which is the likelihood column.   Xdata is where my independent variables are.

Comment: Oh, in that case I think you are just getting the order of the arguments mixed up, it should be `sm.OLS(yData, xData)`, and you should be `add_constanting()` your `xData`, not your `yData`.

Comment: @Marius you're right.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Can anyone suggest what to use instead?  `I am facing similar issues? ValueError: shapes (260,0) and (260,0) not aligned: 0 (dim 1) != 260 (dim 0)`

Comment: The OLS part runs, its the `print(res.summary())` that fails

Comment: Did you get an answer @ctrl-alt-delet